# How to save data from API to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote a program which consumes external API and it works great. I went through SO and other resources but can't solve my problem. I'm quite new to c#. I created model `GetEquipment` where I store data returned from API and `EquipmentDb` which is a SQL table where I want to insert data. I tried to save it this way:

**Consume API:**

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<GetEquipment>> GetDataFromAPI()
    {
         try
         {
             var token = await _accountService.GetToken(
                  _configuration["CredentialsXY:client_id"],
                  _configuration["CredentialsXY:client_secret"]);

             var equipment = await _callAPIService.GetData(token);

             return equipment;

         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             Debug.Write(e);
             return Enumerable.Empty<GetEquipment>();
         }
     }
```

**Model - SQL table:**

```
    public partial class EquipmentDb
    {
        public string SerialNo { get; set; }
        public double? Latitude { get; set; }
        public double? Longitude { get; set; }
    }
```

**Model - data returned from API:**

```
        public class GetEquipment
        {
            public Item[] items { get; set; }
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public string serial_number { get; set; }
            public Location location { get; set; }
        }
        public class Location
        {
            public float longitude { get; set; }
            public float latitude { get; set; }
        }
```

**Save data to db:**

```
        public async Task Index()
        {
            var result = await GetDataFromAPI();  // result from API

            using (var ctx = new HUDAContext())
            {
                var equipment = new EquipmentDb(); // SQL table

                    foreach(var item in result)
                    {
                        equipment.SerialNo = item.items.serial_number,  // here I iterate through 'result' where I store data from API but it does not work, 'items' is highlighted
                        equipment.Latitude = item.items.location.latitude,
                        equipment.Latitude = item.items.location.longitude
                    };

                ctx.EquipmentDbs.Add(equipment);
                await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
            }                                            
        }
```

Inserting data is not working, I try to assign data from `result` to each field in my SQL table but it doesn't work out.

Comment: Why are you looping through `result` and assigning to the same instance of `equipment` on each iteration?

Comment: As Kirk said, the way you're looping through result and saving to the same instance of equipment means you'll only ever save a single EquipmentDb to the database.

In addition your call to GetEquipment() looks strange. With the code you have posted GetEquipment is a class but you're calling it like a method. Did you mean this?
```
var result =  await GetDataFromAPI();
```

Comment: Yes, I meant GetDataFromAPI, made a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from the question exactly how the data is formed. The important thing to understand is **you have two collection wrappers**: the `IEnumerable` in the API result, which includes the `Item[]` inside it. You have to look *inside* both of those.

However, I suspect you only ever expect one result for one or the other (again: it's not clear which from the question). With that in mind, you might want either this:

```
public async Task Index()
{
    var result = await GetEquipment();  // result from API
    var transformed = result.Select(e =>
          new EquipmentDB {
              SerialNo = e.items[0].serial_number,  // here I iterate through 'result' where I store data from API but it does not work, 'items' is highlighted
              Latitude = e.items[0].location.latitude,
              Latitude = e.items[0].location.longitude
          }
    );

    using var ctx = new HUDAContext();
    foreach(var item in transformed)
    {
        ctx.EquipmentDbs.Add(item);
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }                                            
}
```

Or this:

```
public async Task Index()
{
    var result = await GetEquipment();  // result from API
    var transformed = result.First().Select(e =>
          new EquipmentDB {
              SerialNo = e.serial_number,  // here I iterate through 'result' where I store data from API but it does not work, 'items' is highlighted
              Latitude = e.location.latitude,
              Latitude = e.location.longitude
          }
    );

    using var ctx = new HUDAContext();
    foreach(var item in transformed)
    {
        ctx.EquipmentDbs.Add(item);
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }                                            
}
```

And again, you might really need to do *both* (look at `SelectMany()` for this), and visit at each element inside the enumerable, and for each of those elements visit each item inside the array.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using EF, and EquipmentDB is your context class you'd want to create a new equipmentDB object within the foreach e.g:

```
foreach(var item in result)
{
   ctx.EquipmentDbs.Add(new EquipmentDb
   {
      SerialNo = item.items.serial_number, 
      Latitude = item.items.location.latitude,
      Latitude = item.items.location.longitude
   });
};
```

otherwise your just overriding the same object and will only save the last result.

Then Call the save after the loop is done with your new populated list :)!

-Also assuming you meant GetDataFromAPI instead of GetEquipment()

Answer (score -1):

*Try saving it to a list first, and then call AddRange on the context*

```
        public async Task Index(){
            var result = await GetEquipment();  // result from API

            using (HUDAContext ctx = new HUDAContext())
            {
                
                List<EquipmentDb> equipmentlist = new List<EquipmentDb>()

                    foreach(var item in result)
                    {
                        equipmentlist.add(new EquipmentDb{
                            SerialNo = item.items.serial_number, 
                            Latitude = item.items.location.latitude, 
                            Longitude = item.items.location.longitude
                        })
                    };

                ctx.EquipmentDbs.AddRange(equipmentlist);
                await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
            }                                            
        }
```